# How to keep the element justified with available space and arranged vertically with correct space

Tags: html, css

I am trying to arrange the element justifed with available space as well as keep them vertically with same order. but not able to achieve the same.

is there any way to do it?

here is my Code:

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50%;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button>one</button>
  <button>two</button>
  <button>three</button>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <button>one</button>
  <button>two</button>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <button>two</button>
  <button>three</button>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <button>one</button>
  <button>three</button>
</div>
```

Looking the result like :

[image: result I look forward]

Comment: Are you fine with bootstrap??

Comment: no, i am looking the solution with css3

Comment: check my answer. thanks

Comment: why not use space between them?

Comment: @Shizukura - it's in table column, the width varies according to the data load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS Grids. However, you would need to add some additional markup to prevent your buttons' widths from expanding *(if there is a CSS fix to this, please let me know)*.

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div><button>one</button></div>
  <div><button>two</button></div>
  <div><button>three</button></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div><button>one</button></div>
  <div><button>two</button></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div><button>two</button></div>
  <div><button>three</button></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div><button>one</button></div>
  <div><button>three</button></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try with this code.

```css
.parent {
  border:1px solid red;
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}
.parent_inner{
width:calc(100% / 3);
float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="parent_inner"><button class='button'>one</button></div>
 <div class="parent_inner"><button class='button'>two</button></div>
 <div class="parent_inner"><button class='button'>three</button></div>

</div>
<div class="parent">
 <div class="parent_inner"><button class='button'>one</button></div>
 <div class="parent_inner"><button class='button'>two</button></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
<div class="parent_inner"><button class='button'>two</button></div>
 <div class="parent_inner"><button class='button'>three</button></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
<div class="parent_inner"><button class='button'>one</button></div>
 <div class="parent_inner"><button class='button'>three</button></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Out!

```
<style>
  .parent,.parent1 {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
  }

  .parent1>div {
    width: 33%;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .parent>div {
    width: 33%;
    text-align: center;
  }

</style>

<div class="parent1">
  <div>
    <button>one</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>two</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>three</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <button>one</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>two</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <button>two</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>three</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <button>one</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>three</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can get more info about FlexBox here:-

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Comment: your answer not works. i required to align buttons vertically with same line. still if there is 1 button or 2 button.

Comment: added, please check in my question

Answer (score 0):

used `Grid` to achieve it. you can go through below link for more info. thanks
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid.asp

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'auto auto auto';
  grid-template-columns: 33.33% 33.33% 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <button class='button1'>one</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class='button1'>two</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class='button1'>three</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <button class='button1'>one</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class='button1'>two</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <button class='button1'>two</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class='button1'>three</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <button class='button1'>one</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class='button1'>three</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If there is no button as 'one' then it will be replaced by 'two' check my requirement screen shot. it should left aligned, either 1 button or more

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS grid to achieve what you want. It is supported by all major browsers.

IE 11 support is outdated but all the other major browsers support the current spec. Including Edge.

- Can I Use link: https://caniuse.com/#search=grid
- CSS Grid complete guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50%;
  /* these rows will set up the grid */
  display: grid;
  /* 3 columns one third width of the container */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.parent button {
  /* This will tell the buttons to align 
     themselves to the left of the grid cell 
     If you wish the buttons to fill the 
     whole width of the cell, you could remove this */
  justify-self: start;
}

/* First button in first cell */
.parent button:first-child {
  grid-column: 1;
}

/* and so on... */
.parent button:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.parent button:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button>one</button>
  <button>two</button>
  <button>three</button>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <button>one</button>
  <button>two</button>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <button>two</button>
  <button>three</button>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <button>one</button>
  <button>three</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

add this to CSS:

```
.button{
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

and instead of `<button>` use `<button class="button">`

here [live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ts0Lu8qy/)